# How to trim the column in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, trim

i have a gridview, the column has 20 records whose values are in decimal.say like 5686252.345656 i want to trim those value. So that i could see 5686252.34. It would be great if i trim it in the c# code rather in SQL.

Ive binded the values like this..

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Weighted Avg" SortExpression="WT_AVG"
 ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" HeaderStyle-Width="70px">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="lblWT" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"WT_AVG") %>' />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: A `GridViewColumn` has not 20 _records_. You should make more of an effort

Comment: it's possible to bind your gridview to a collection that's not necessaraly direct from the database.  you can do the trimming in-between

Comment: You need to go accept answers on your previous questions.....

Comment: @Blachshma It is clear that the OP knows how to accept an answer. Now it his/her wish to accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a format string to the binding statement:
Example:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price", "{0:c}") %>
```

Comment: +1, but you should probably explain, or link to documentation of format strings anyway.

Comment: I think it helps the OP more if they learn how to search rather than spoon feed them information.

Comment: It helps the OP more if you spoon feed them information,  than if you spoon feed them just code

Comment: Actually i dont need the dollar symbol near the value. So ive used     "{0:N2}".. Thnkas alot..

Answer (score 0):

I would use Math.Round(decimal d,int decimals) for example

```
Math.Round(3.44, 1); //Returns 3.4.
Math.Round(3.45, 1); //Returns 3.4.
Math.Round(3.46, 1); //Returns 3.5.
Math.Round(4.34, 1); // Returns 4.3
Math.Round(4.35, 1); // Returns 4.4
Math.Round(4.36, 1); // Returns 4.4
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k(v=vs.100).aspx

EDIT: OR do it in the SQL:

```
SELECT ROUND(123.9994,3), ROUND(123.9995,3)
returns: 123.9990 124.0000
```

[Rounding on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't think that the OP is having troubles truncating his values when they're already in the code-behind, I think he's having trouble performing arithmetic operations on it, and then bringing it back to the grid-view.

Comment: The OP Specifically states he needs the values 'trimed' which will be done if they use Math.Round...
**OPs example: ""say like 5686252.345656 i want to trim those value. So that i could see 5686252.34"**